# Flutter GetIn can't find the method of the services

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, stacked

I'm setting up a project with Flutter. I want to register services with GetIn. But I'm not able to find the methods of the service that I want to use.

This is the class locator in which I register the service, for example MongoDBService.

```
import 'package:app/services/mongodb.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final locator = GetIt.instance;
    
setupLocator() {
    locator.registerSingleton<MongoDBService>(MongoDBService());
}
```

Then when I want to use the MongoDBService I am not able to find the functions that belong to the service.

```
void connect() async {
    await mongo.beginConnection();
}
  
final mongo = locator<MongoDBService>;
```

The error is on beginConnection which is not defined. But currently it is defined in the MongoDBService.

Also I setup the locator by calling the `setupLocator` function in the main.

```
void main() {
    setupLocator();
    runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `final mongo = locator<MongoDBService>;` in the `connect` method.

```
void connect() async {
    final mongo = locator<MongoDBService>();
    await mongo.beginConnection();
}
```

Comment: Why it should change something? I tried it anyway and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Oh hey @carlo97, it seems like `()` is missing, please check my edit.

Comment: You are right. I can use `final mongo = locator<MongoDBService>();` as global variable but I was missing the last rounded parenthesis.